# Putting eigenvalues of a matrix in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix `mainmatrix` which must be multiplied by `a` `(a={0.1, 0.2, 0.3,....1})`. In any iteration, we have to save the matrix's eigenvalues in a list.

I wrote the code

```
mainmatrix={{-1, 1, 0, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1, -1, 0}, 
{0, 1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1, -1, 1}};

Do[list[10 i + 1]=Eigenvalues[i*mainmatrix],{i, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

But when read the `list[1]` or `list[2]` or any of them I see nothing!! Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: I think I should use `Round[10*i+1]`

Comment: Three comments:  First, you may find it more convenient to just store the results in a list, rather than in a function -- ie `alllists=Table[Eigenvalues[i*mainmatrix],{i,0,1,0.1}]`.  Second, if you multiply a matrix by a constant, the eigenvalues just scale.  Third, for your code, try `list[1.]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is rising from the `10*i+1` we have to use

`Do[ list[Round[10i+1]]=Eigenvalues[i*mainmatrix],{i,0,1,0.1}]`